# ERROR: MethodError: no method matching abs(::Array{Complex{Float64},1})

Tags: julia

let's suppose that we have this function:

```
function prob(na)
            @assert count(!iszero, ui2*na) == 0
            b = T0*na
            setc(-b)
            total = 0.0
            for x in Channel(scan)
                nab = vi2*x + b 
                total += prod([c.^complex(n)/factorial(n) for (c, n) in zip(coef, nab)])
            end
            return abs(total*omega)^2
        end
```

and let's try to ignore some variables in this function since the problem is not related to them, the problem that i'm facing here is when i call this function which is by the way an intern function, i get this following error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching abs(::Array{Complex{Float64},1})
Closest candidates are:
  abs(::Bool) at bool.jl:83
  abs(::Float16) at float.jl:520
  abs(::Float32) at float.jl:521
  ...
```

now i know that the error is in the last part `abs(total*omega)^2` , `coef`and `nab`are coefficients type `Int` `omega`also is `Int`, if i try the same operation on a simple case it would work but here it doesn't i don't know why!!

Comment: `omega` ist probably not an integer. Put a `@show typeof(omega)` before the `abs` call to confirm this.

Comment: Clearly, `total*omega` is a vector, and you cannot take `abs` of a vector. Did you expect it to be a scalar? Almost _none_ of the variables in your function are defined, please provide runnable code.

Answer (score 3):

`total` seems to be a `Vector` of complex numbers and `omega` is probably some scalar.
Hence, probably it will be enough if you vectorize your operations using the do (`.`) operator. Have a look at the code below:

```
julia> cnums = Complex.([2,2,3],[2,7,6])
3-element Array{Complex{Int64},1}:
 2 + 2im
 2 + 7im
 3 + 6im

julia> abs.(cnums .* 1).^2
3-element Array{Float64,1}:
  8.000000000000002
 53.0
 45.00000000000001
```

Or, better suggested by @DNF:

```
julia> abs2.(cnums .* 1)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  8
 53
 45
```

Comment: Definitely use `abs2.(cnums)` instead of `abs.(cnums).^2`. The performance difference is in some cases staggering, since `abs2` can be simd'ed, while `abs` is not. Also it's simply cleaner.

Comment: Also probably it is `omega` that is a vector (a global one) as `total` is defined inside a function and it is a scalar. As an additional broadcasting cleanup it is better to write `abs2.(cnums .* 1)` to use broadcasting fusion - such code should run faster.

Comment: i'm sorry for some reason i wasn't able to answer your suggestions, after i fixed this by using `abs2`i get another BoundError, apparently it raises in the for loop: `BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{JuMP.Variable,1} at index [1]` and for more explanation there is a variable was created called `x`in another function using `Clp` that is called using `Channel`, `@variable(m, x[1:level])`with this constraint: `@constraint(m, con, A*x.>=0)`and i don't really know how to fix this.

Comment: Perhaps you have a variable of size `0`? Maybe `level=0`? Perhaps you should make a MWE with the optimization code and post it as a separate question?